# Open Main Window of SwiftUI app that has been closed and is not visible in Dock

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing an app in SwiftUI that has a main window but also a `MenuBarExtra`.
In the settings there is an option to hide the main window from the dock (this is a feature of my app where the app can only run in the menu bar).

Once the window has been closed, I want the user to be able to reopen it.

I have added the following code:

```
@main
struct MyApp : App
{
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.showInMenuBar) var showInMenuBar = false
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "MainWindow") {
            ContentView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        }
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
        
        MenuBarExtra("ScannerMainItem", systemImage: "rectangle.stack", isInserted: $showInMenuBar) {
            Button(LocalizedStringKey("OPEN_MAIN_WINDOW")) {
                self.openWindow(id: "MainWindow")
            }.keyboardShortcut("m")
            
            Divider()
            
            Button(LocalizedStringKey("QUIT")) {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }.keyboardShortcut("q")
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if the main window has been closed. However, if the main window is still open, another (new) instance will be opened.
How can I only have one window with id "Main" open at any time?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a couple of hours and came up with a workaround. There are probably better ways to do it, but right now I'm happy I've got something that works.

```
Button(LocalizedStringKey("OPEN_MAIN_WINDOW")) {
  openApp(id: "MainWindow")
}.keyboardShortcut("m")
```

..

```
func openApp(id: String) {
  NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
  let windowCount = NSWindow.windowNumbers()?.count
  if let windowCount {
    if windowCount <= 2 {
      openWindow(id: id)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This only works when debugging. It seems like the call to activate takes too long. By the time the next line is executed, the window is not (yet) instantiated.

Comment: Great that you figured out a way to get it working in your app. 
I guess the difference could be that I'm not using toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @o.hennig I adjusted the code a little bit:

```
func openApp(id: String) {
  NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        
  if !NSApplication.shared.windows.contains(where: { $0.toolbar.hasValue })
  {
    self.openWindow(id: id)
  }
}
```

Just a workaround, but my window is the only window with a toolbar...